# how to write Russian in resource file?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

If anyone is having idea how to write Russian in resource file I m editing the existing resource file in english and want to write the values of strings in russian but I m trying to copy paste from some editor and visual studio is not detecting it. Do I need to install sth so that visual studio recognize it...

Thanks,

Comment: Is your .rc file a unicode file?  I understand that unicode .rc files are supported, but not created by default

Comment: I m using .resx file and using strings....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Visual Studio isn't special in any way and I don't have Russian language support installed.  Everything works just fine. Resource editor should be unicode aware, that's the whole point of resources (localization).

[alt text http://img513.imageshack.us/img513/315/russianh.png](http://img513.imageshack.us/img513/315/russianh.png)